# String drip system while summer away for 1 month

Tags: watering, plant-care

Is it suitable to string drip while summer? I am away for 1 month in April. I have 10 pots in my garden. so I decided to create string dripping. But is this suitable? If not, then what is the best option for self watering ??

It is Mid Summer In Maharashtra.

I had chilly, tomato, rose, lemongrass, and like plants and had enough water source.

Any suggestions accepted.

Comment: what kind of plant, what amount of sun, what part of the world.  What water sources do you have.  Help us help you and give us some details

Comment: It is Mid Summer In Maharashtra. and I had : chilly, tomato, rose ,. like plants

Comment: As reference: Mumbai weather in April: average high 33.0°C (91.4°F), with top 42.2°C. Average rainfall 0.7mm. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumbai#Climate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to ask a friend or neighbor. You could pay them with some tomatoes.

If you want healthy plants after you are returning, the plants need water, but also people that harvest the tomatoes and other fruits. Otherwise, you will get some rot tomatoes together with insects and possibly diseases. Additionally tomato plants will reduce or temporarily stop to produce new tomatoes.

Comment: yes.. you are right.. I should do this.. but still for my information is there any possible way for self water ?

Comment: Whith such hot weather? Automatic water yes (a timer that gives every day x liter water), self water: I doubt (but I don't live in such climate). Automatic watering is cheap (basic models), if you have a faucet nearby (or a large container)..

Comment: yes I have 1000lt container